# onActivityResult doesn't return success

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm asking the user to rate my app and navigating them to google playstore.

```
fun openPlayStore() {
        val appPackageName = packageName
        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName")
                ), OPEN_PLAY_STORE
            )
        } catch (anfe: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            startActivityForResult(
                Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")
                ), OPEN_PLAY_STORE
            )
        }
    }
```

Then, to check user successfully went to playstore or not

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
if (requestCode == OPEN_PLAY_STORE) {
            println(" resultCode = > $resultCode")
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}
```

Here, I'm getting toast when user presses cancel. But I'm not getting Toast when user successfully navigated to playstore.

Comment: you have forgotten to set result to your intent

Comment: @WhatAJerk I'm not getting what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible but you can do some workaround.

```
// Logic to ask rating when user opened the app 5th time
        val sp = this.getSharedPreferences("UserLoginCount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        userLoginCount = sp.getInt("count", 1)
        userLoginCountPrevious = sp.getInt("count", 0)
        var showRatingDialogCount = sp.getInt("nextCount", 5)

        if (userLoginCount == showRatingDialogCount) {
            openAskForRating()
        } else {
            sp.edit().putInt("count", ++userLoginCount).commit()
            Toast.makeText(this,"$userLoginCount time user logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

- have two variable `userLoginCount` and `userLoginCountPrevious`
- read from shared pref's `userLoginCount` then save it's val to `userLoginCountPrevious`
- when user login 5th time here as in this example, Rating dialog is showed. else increment the value of `userLoginCount`.
- now you can see that `userLoginCount` is incremented but not `userLoginCountPrevious`.

Then, in on `onActivityResult`

```
if (userLoginCount == userLoginCountPrevious) { 
     // means he successfully navigated to playstore and came back 
     dialog.dismiss()
}else{
     // means he closed the rating dialog without visiting playstore
}
```

Hope, it helps !

Comment: This makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if the user is redirected to play store or not.

When you start an intent using `startActivityForResult`then next activity should call `setResult` before closing. Only then you can fetch result from the next activity in your `onActivityResult`.

In this case play store doesn't set result and hence you don't get any result in your `onActivityResult`